# Can't connect to redis using django-redis

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, redis, django-redis

I've got a django project using django-redis 3.8.0 to connect to an aws instance of redis. However, I receive `ConnectionError: Error 111 connecting to None:6379. Connection refused.` when trying to connect. If I ssh into my ec2 and use redis-py from the shell, I am able to read and write from the cache just fine, so I don't believe it's a security policy issue.

Comment: could you post your django settings file (did you set `REDIS_HOST`)?

Comment: The only redis specific setting I have is:  `CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": "myawsredislocation:6379",
        'KEY_PREFIX': 'projectname',
        "OPTIONS": {
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
        }
    }
}`

Comment: Are you running redis on your on ec2 instance, or using their (AWS's) elastic-cache redis?

Comment: You say if you ssh into your ec2 instance (I'm assuming this is also the instance running redis) you are able to connect to redis... this would imply a localhost connection and isn't even touching any AWS firewall security groups.  Where is django running from?

Comment: Redis is being run using AWS's elastic-cache.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok, figured it out. What I needed to do was prefix my location with `redis://`. This is specific to the django-redis library and how it parses the location url. That explains why when I manually set up a StrictRedis connection using the python redis library I was able to connect.

Comment: For other users having this problem who have a non-AWS Redis server, I found that adding the "redis://" prefix to the LOCATION key wasn't sufficient.  I also had to add my server's IP address to the 'bind' directive in /etc/redis/redis.conf.  The file says Redis listens on all ports by default but I didn't find this to be the case.  In fact, I could remove the 'redis' protocol prefix and it still worked so long as I was binding redis to my server's IP.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running elastic-cache redis, you can't access it from outside AWS - that is why you are getting the error.

From AWS FAQ:

> Please note that IP-range based access control is currently not
>   enabled for Cache Clusters. **All clients to a Cache Cluster must be
>   within the EC2 network, and authorized via security groups as
>   described above.**

http://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/faqs/

Comment: I'm not accessing it from outside AWS, I'm accessing from an ec2 instance. And I'm able to access the cache from said instance using the redis-py library so I can verify that the security groups have been set up correctly.